# Working with object `Date()`, how can I compare between hours?

Tags: javascript, date

I need to compare hours:

```
var myDate = new Date().getHours();

if (myDate === 07 || myDate === 08) // condition if user's current time is between 7 and 8 AM
{
     // do something
}
else if (myDate == 08 || myDate === 09) // condition if user's current time is between 8 AM and 9 AM
    // and so on...
}
```

what would an elegant way be to compare it for each interval of an hour (07-08, 08-09 and so on)?

Comment: Your first `if` will work if the time is between `07:00:00` and `08:59:59` - is this what you really want?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol will `myDate >= 07 && myDate <= 08` solve that? I am looking for a more elegant way, definitely.

Comment: No, that'll still do the same. If you want between `07:00:00` and `07:59:59` then you just want the hour to be `=== 7`. At that point, you can just use `switch(new Date().getHours()) { case 7: ...`

Comment: You can use [Date.getHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours). It returns the hour for the specified date - so if Date obj is const birthday = new Date ('13 Mar, 08 04:20 ') (used example from mdn), birthday.getHours() will return 4 until the hour changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to improve your code? Let me count the ways...

1. Name the variable something appropriate. It is storing the current hour, not a date, so calling it `myDate` is inappropriate.
2. The hour is not going to be changing during the running of the code. For the lifetime of the code at least, it is `const`ant. Designate it as such.

   ```
   const currentHour = (new Date()).getHours();
   ```
3. When the time is between 7AM and 8AM, the hour will equal 7. If it equals 8, then you've gone past the time of 8AM. So, for that hour block, you only care if the hour is exactly 7.
4. Numbers are numbers. Leading zeroes are irrelevant, and in older engines will outright fail for `08` and `09` as the leading zero makes it considered an octal number, which doesn't allow 8 or 9.
5. When you have one thing to compare against multiple values, that's exactly what `switch` is for.

   ```
   switch( currentHour) {
   case 7:
       // do something when it is between 07:00:00 and 07:59:59
       break;
   case 8:
       // do something else when it is between 08:00:00 and 08:59:59
       break;
   }
   ```

Additional note, if you want to do the same thing for more than an hour, you can do that.

```
case 9:
case 10:
    // do the same thing from 09:00:00 to 10:59:59
    break;
```

Comment: is 8:00:00 is case 7 or case 8 ?

Comment: @jsduniya When the clock shows a `7` in the hours position, then it is `case 7`. When it shows an `8` in the hours position, then it is `case 8`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was confused with the logic to stop `if` condition at 07:59.